# Cloning A Git Repo With Submodules

Tags: git, eclipse, git-submodules, git-clone, wizard

How can I clone a git repository that has a submodule into an eclipse workspace? 
When I am done cloning, the submodule directory is empty
and the project doesn't appear in the workspace. I've read:

> **Cloning Repositories with Submodules**
>
> Submodules are repositories nested inside a parent repository.
> Therefore when doing a clone of a parent repository it is necessary to clone the submodule repositories so that the files/folders are available in the parent repository's working directory.
>
> Checking the Clone Submodules button from the Git Clone wizard will clone all submodule repositories after the clone of the parent
> repository finishes.

[image: Clone Git Repository Window]

Answer (score 1):

in eclipse go to git explorer perspective

you can import you project modules under you project

```
project> working directory > select sub module > import project.
  >> Import as general project (for new)
  >> Import existing project (which will replace you current project)
```

if you have 3 modules you need to import one by one. as existing module or new one

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work, it says there are no projects to import, though in the git repo i see a definite connection to the project

Comment: i can able to clone from local repo, and i am able to clone submodules and copied to new workspace, by the way mine is windows and eclipse indigo version, this might be an issue with eclipse version you use. by the way i personally dont use eclipse for git related stuff, i prefer to use command for git task, due to buggy git plugins

Answer (score 0):

1. git clone yourProjectUrl.
2. in your project folder: git submodule init (only do it first time)
3. you can also update submodule: git submodule update.

Comment: is it not possible to do through eclipse ?

Comment: I never use eclipse to manage git. I always use command line.